# Direct delete on server side Easy Table, then sync on client side

Tags: ios, azure, azure-mobile-services

This question involves iOS 9.3 client app syncing data with Easy Table on MS Azure backend:

I made a mobile app on Azure. Then I download its objective-C starter project. I'm looking at MSSyncTable's header file and docs. I've tried out the
 insert, delete, update, and some of the read methods and they all work great.

Via the docs, generally they work in a way where MSSyncContext's data source  delete/add/update the given item in the local store. Then it queues a request to send the delete/add/update to the mobile service.

I tested it with multiple clients and the results all worked very well.

However, I'm interested in what will happen in a situation where the user deletes on the server directly. In other words, say I go to my portal's Easy Table and make a delete directly on 'Ricky' like so:

[image]

Then I pull to refresh on my client. I get this error log in my xCode's console:

**-[QSTodoService logErrorIfNotNil:] - ERROR Error Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1170 "Not all operations completed successfully" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Not all operations completed successfully, com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorPushResultKey=(
    "The item does not exist",
    "The item does not exist"
)}**

This is expected because the client app is trying to refresh on the data Ricky from the Server. However data Ricky is not there because I just removed it.

Now, the situation is that the client app's local data **Ricky** is still there. Also, the request to refresh data Ricky is always on the client's service queue. Thus, everything I do from now on, will have give me this error because the request to "refresh data Ricky" always gets sent, and as a result, the "item does not exist" message will naturally always come back.

So my question is, is there a way to resolve this particular issue?

Or is it that this particular case of usage is illegal and should never be done?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I have tried using MSSyncTable's forcePurgeWithCompletion method to purge all local data, pending operations, etc...just as the method doc has specified.

However, method gives me an NSError: [Code=-1180 "The table cannot be purged because it has pending operations that have been sent to the server and not yet received a response]

Not sure, how I would go about removing those pending operations so my forcePurgeWithCompletion will work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that you are trying to update a record that no longer exists.  This causes a 404 Not Found error which is trapped and generates the error on the client.

If you wish to delete a record, you should set the `deleted` flag on the row to true.  This is then propagated to the clients and the clients then delete the records.

If you get into this state, you need to use the `Purge` (or PurgeAsync) on the local store.  This will remove the data from the table and the operations queue, allowing you to re-sync the data from the server.

Comment: I'm developing for iOS, so I would then need to use MSSyncTable's forcePurgeWithCompletion. However, it won't let me force purge because: [Code=-1180 "The table cannot be purged because it has pending operations that have been sent to the server and not yet received a response]. Are there any sample code or references around? I went through MS's docs and I couldn't find any samples that can show me how to do this.

Comment: Use PushAsync() before PurgeAsync().

Comment: can you tell me what class PushAsync and PurgeAsync belong to?